# Heroku Python import local functions

Tags: python, heroku

I'm developing a chatbot using heroku and python. I have a file fetchWelcome.py in which I have written a function. I need to import the function from fetchWelcome into my main file.

I wrote `from fetchWelcome import fetchWelcome` in main file. But because we need to mention all the dependencies in the requirement file, it shows error. I don't know how to mention user defined requirement.
How can I import the function from another file into the main file ? Both the files ( main.py and fetchWelcome.py ) are in the same folder.

Comment: Consider dropping "Heroku" from the title of this question.

Comment: @ChadVanDeHey I know how to import function from another files when working locally. I need to do the same when I deploy my code on Heroku server.

Answer (score 2):

You're quite close to the answer to the question. Importing works like this:

**fetchWelcome.py:**

```
def foo():
    # Do something here
    print("Hello World")

def bar():
    # Do something else
    print("Python")
```

**main.py:**

```
import fetchWelcome

fetchWelcome.foo()
fetchWelcome.bar()
```

If you only want to import a single function, use

```
from fetchWelcome import foo

foo()
```

Both files have to be in the same folder.

Comment: The answer you posted is correct but I need to know how can I do the same when I deploy the code on Heroku server.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide additional information. What are you trying to do? Which files are in which folder? Post your "requirement file" and your shortened source code.

Comment: @fecavy Found the answer. If we need to import function from fetchWelcome.py into main.py, write "from .fetchWelcome import functionName". Thus we don't need to write any dependency in requirement file.

Answer (score 0):

If we need to import function from fileName into main.py, write

```
from .fileName import functionName
```

Thus we don't need to write any dependency in requirement file.